# How to Capture Multiple New lines between two characters?

Tags: regex, sed

I am trying to match and remove multiple newlines between quotations to clean up a CSV file. SED is what I am most familiar with, but am happy to use whatever assuming I have access to it.

Example

```
"ABC","This is
a
test
","1","2","This
is
another
test"
```

Expected End Result

```
"ABC","This is a test","1","2","This is another test"
```

I've tried multiple patterns on `regex101.com` and looked around the "similar questions," but can't seem to find anything remotely close to working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this `gnu awk`:

```sh
awk -v RS='"[^"]+"' 'RT {gsub(/"\n+|\n+"/, "\"", RT); gsub(/\n+/, " ", RT)} {ORS=RT} 1' file.csv

"ABC","This is a test","1","2","This is another test"
```

Comment: This is great. I really need to stop putting off learning Awk. Thank you!